Two approaches to tensors?
This is a soft question so I'm not completely sure if it is appropriate here, but anyway.
Lately I have been studying tensors as I'm working with tensor-machine-learning. Initially I used standard mathematics/physics introduction to tensors, where in some sense it is more grounded to abstract algebra. In particular, co/contra-variance is discussed, changes of basis, connections to vector and dual spaces, etc. I also encountered the connections to calculus/analysis here, like the higher order Jacobian (partials), the various special tensors etc.
However it turns out my research didn't require those, and instead treated a tensor as a purely 'data matrix'. Here, I encounter decompositions, such as tucker/cp and their various generalizations. And to be honest, I can't really fathom a situation where entries to my data tensor would be co/contra-variant.
My question: Where is the connection between these two seemingly disjoint areas?

As a data structure tensors are multidimensional arrays. Many useful operations can still be performed on them using matrix multiplication or the Kronecker product even when the data isn't numerical. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_(data_type)

In short: in calculus and differential geometry we should call them tensor fields that is: functions with values in the higher order matrices. Co- and contravariance comes in when we change coordinates.

@KurtG., covariance and contravariance are meaningful for tensors per se and not just tensor fields.

Abstractly, tensors are essentially generalizations of linear functions and maps to multilinear functions and maps. Written with respect to a basis, they become multidimensional matrices. Presumably, in machine learning, you always use them with respect to a fixed basis and therefore the abstract point of view becomes less useful.

I've never been able to make a solid connection between the two senses, and physicists seem to have their own framework for "tensors". Whenever I hear the word "tensor" these days I always ask "in which sense?", and think of them as different as the word "shift" used in a car versus a keyboard.

The main difference is the inner product space you use. If your metric is $\delta_{ij}$ (Euclidean space) then the distinction between covariant and contravariant indices disappears. Index notation can still be useful for writing things down concisely; but you do not have to worry about $x^i$ having different transformation properties from $x_i$.  So whether you present an image by writing $T_{ijk}$ or ${T^k}_{ij}$ or any other combination you are still dealing with the same set of numbers. If machine learning operated in a different metric space this would not be the case.
